# Export/Import microsoft flow in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate, microsoft-flow

I have created the flow on particular Site-Collection and after that successfully run on **Microsoft flow**.

Is it possible to export/import flows in order to have a backup option?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Flagging this question as off-topic because it is about Microsoft Flow, not SharePoint. Remember, Office365 is *not* SharePoint or SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was no such functionality to import/export flows or any other backup option previously.

But you can configure **Data Loss Prevention** (DLP) policies as shown [here](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/guided-learning/learning-data-loss-prevention/) for prevention.

## UPDATE

As per @**SP Combatant**'s answer **now you can import and export the flows**:

**Export a Flow:**

1. click on ellipsis "..." menu, select 'Export' then click on 'Package
   (.zip)'
2. provide a name and a description for your package and configure other options
3. click on the "Export" button in the bottom right corner your package should start downloading shortly after (or click "Download" button)

**Import a Flow:**

- click on the import button in the top right hand corner of the screen upload the package file and wait for the screen to show up the package details

These instruction are provided from this page which contains helpful animations too. https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/import-export-bap-packages/

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  You absolutely can import and export Flow's.

Comment: See correct answer below.

Comment: @SPCombatant your answer is based on latest development in MS Flow.. the existing answer may be right at that timeframe..

Comment: @ArunVinoth, your are accurate, but if you are like me and came here looking for an answer, that answer is no longer correct, hence the comment and the correct answer below. No disrespect intended.  Just wanted to keep this thread up to date. Thanks

Comment: Then you have to post your comment in question.. so every user will read it. @SPCombatant

Comment: @SP Combatant thanks for updating. This functionality was not there before when I had given this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Export a Flow:

1. click on ellipsis "..." menu, select 'Export' then click on 'Package (.zip)'
2. provide a name and a description for your package and configure other options
3. click on the "Export" button in the bottom right corner your package should start downloading shortly after (or click "Download" button)

Import a Flow:

1. click on the import button in the top right hand corner of the screen
   upload the package file and wait for the screen to show up the package details

These instruction are provided from this page which contains helpful animations too.
https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/import-export-bap-packages/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete step by step process on how to export and improt Microsfot Flow:

https://global-sharepoint.com/2019/08/06/sharepoint-online-export-and-import-microsoft-flow/

Comment: Is this from your own blog post?